# PHP fastest way to check if string is UTF-8?

Tags: php, performance, utf-8, benchmarking

there are several ways to check if a string is valid UTF-8 in PHP, but has anyone actually benchmarked to check which method is faster?

ways to check that i know of (maybe it's missing something, idk):

```php
function is_utf8_1(string $str): bool
{
    return mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
}

function is_utf8_2(string $str): bool
{
    return (bool) preg_match('//u', $str);
}

function is_utf8_3(string $str): bool
{
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str) === $str;
}


// DO NOT USE is_utf8_4, it is bugged, it incorrectly validates "\xC0\x81"
//
// in 2009 the author made the claim that
//  this method is more accurate than mb_check_encoding,
// without providing any examples of where mb_check_encdoing fails and this function succeeds...
// source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php#95289
function is_utf8_4(string $str): bool
{
    $len = strlen($str);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++ $i) {
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if ($c > 128) {
            if (($c > 247))
                return false;
            elseif ($c > 239)
                $bytes = 4;
            elseif ($c > 223)
                $bytes = 3;
            elseif ($c > 191)
                $bytes = 2;
            else
                return false;
            if (($i + $bytes) > $len)
                return false;
            while ($bytes > 1) {
                ++ $i;
                $b = ord($str[$i]);
                if ($b < 128 || $b > 191)
                    return false;
                -- $bytes;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you need to check that many trillions of strings that this difference actually matters, you’ll want to conduct your own benchmark on your own data on your particular platform. In any other case, just use the function that is intended for exactly this purpose: `mb_check_encoding`.

Comment: It sounds like a significant part of your question is the claim of "more accurate than `mb_check_encoding`" for the `is_utf8_4`, and whether that's worth whatever performance cost it might involve.  You should probably link where you found it.

Comment: @deceze it appears that preg_match is *SIGNIFICANTLY* faster than mb_check_encoding though, like 30 times faster(!!!), makes me wonder if i made a mistake in the benchmarking code somehow.. or perhaps mb_check_encoding has a performance issue somehow (or perhaps someone spent a lot more effort optimizing preg_match than anyone has spent optimizing mb_check_encoding ? like maybe preg_match is using SSE instructions while mb_ isn't? idk)

Comment: @PeterCordes i added the link in the source code, and i don't really doubt the accuracy of mb_check_encoding, that code/comment was written 11 years ago (2009-12-24), if there were known issues with `mb_check_encoding($str,'UTF-8')` 11 years ago, there's a good chance it has been fixed since then :)

Comment: @deceze also it seems failure_early is completely un-optimized with mb_check_encoding, it uses basically the same time checking the string regardless if the first invalid bytes is on position 0 or position 4690, like in my benchmark code below, suggesting an `early return` optimization could make mb_check_encoding much faster in the bad/binary-data-case than it is today, hmm

Comment: Please note that neither method is robust or accurate. That is because the task in not solvable. These methods only use heuristics to make a good guess, that is all. All they can tell is whether a string _might_ be valid UTF-8. And two of those methods only check the first 100 or 500 characters in a string. Bottom line: you should _know_ the encoding of the data you work with instead of trying to guess it.

Comment: @arkascha `And two of those methods only check the first 100 or 500 characters` - that's not true, every single method here checks at least the first 4690 bytes inclusive, not a single method failed any of my 3 testcases, if what you said were really true, 2 of them should fail the `failure_late` testcase, but they don't: https://wandbox.org/permlink/DGP6L5mpEN105dYI

Comment: My statement was based on indeed old information. When I check myself to find the cause of issues that is what I found in the documentation of the methods. If it is different now then things have changed in the mean time. Which may very well be the case considering my age ;-) Thanks for correcting my outdated information.

Comment: @arkascha interesting, i wonder if that was the issue the author of method #4 was referring to back in 2009 (he didn't specify what the issue actually was, unfortunately)

Answer (score 2):

in this *simple non-comprehensive* test, preg_match is over 32 times faster than mb_check_encoding, wow! what happened there? it's also 14 times faster than iconv, and 1344 times faster than the userland implementation

benchmarked on a dedicated server rolling `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1240 V2 @ 3.40GHz` with PHP 7.4.13,

running with 1 million iterations yielded

```
root@x-ratma-net:~# time php bench2.php
Array
(
    [is_utf8_1] => Array
        (
            [success] => 37835
            [failure_early] => 37705
            [failure_late] => 37632
        )

    [is_utf8_2] => Array
        (
            [success] => 1147
            [failure_early] => 839
            [failure_late] => 8521
        )

    [is_utf8_3] => Array
        (
            [success] => 16081
            [failure_early] => 15667
            [failure_late] => 15664
        )

    [is_utf8_4] => Array
        (
            [success] => 1542154
            [failure_early] => 943
            [failure_late] => 1542284
        )

)
/root/bench2.php:91:
array(3) {
  'success' =>
  string(9) "is_utf8_2"
  'failure_early' =>
  string(9) "is_utf8_2"
  'failure_late' =>
  string(9) "is_utf8_2"
}

real    5m33.715s
user    5m33.364s
sys     0m0.292s
```

benchmark code:

```
<?php


function is_utf8_1(string $str): bool
{
    return mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
}

function is_utf8_2(string $str): bool
{
    return (bool) preg_match('//u', $str);
}

function is_utf8_3(string $str): bool
{
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str) === $str;
}


// DO NOT USE is_utf8_4, it is bugged, it incorrectly validates "\xC0\x81"
//
// in 2009 the author made the claim that
//  this method is more accurate than mb_check_encoding,
// without providing any examples of where mb_check_encdoing fails and this function succeeds...
// source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php#95289
function is_utf8_4(string $str): bool
{
    $len = strlen($str);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if ($c > 128) {
            if (($c > 247))
                return false;
            elseif ($c > 239)
                $bytes = 4;
            elseif ($c > 223)
                $bytes = 3;
            elseif ($c > 191)
                $bytes = 2;
            else
                return false;
            if (($i + $bytes) > $len)
                return false;
            while ($bytes > 1) {
                ++$i;
                $b = ord($str[$i]);
                if ($b < 128 || $b > 191)
                    return false;
                --$bytes;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$functions = [
    "is_utf8_1",
    "is_utf8_2",
    "is_utf8_3",
    "is_utf8_4",
];
$iterations = 1_000_000;
$results = [];
$test_strings = [];
$repeated = 10;
$test_strings["success"] = "ˈmaʳkʊs kuːn ℕ ⊆ ℕ₀ ⊂ ℤ ⊂ ℚ ⊂ ℝ ⊂ ℂ, ⊥ < a ≠ b ≡ c ≤ d ≪ ⊤ ⇒ (A ⇔ B), Σὲ γνωρίζω ἀπὸ τὴν κόψη Οὐχὶ ταὐτὰ παρίσταταί გთხოვთ ሰማይ አይታረስ ንጉሥ አይከሰስ ᚻᛖ ᚳᚹᚫᚦ ᚦᚫᛏ ᚻᛖ ᛒᚢᛞᛖ ᚩᚾ ᚦᚫᛗ ᛚᚪᚾᛞᛖ ᚾᚩᚱᚦᚹᛖᚪᚱᛞᚢᛗ ᚹᛁᚦ ᚦᚪ ᚹᛖᛥᚫ ";
$test_strings["success"] .= "♔♕♖♗♘♙♚♛♜♝♞";
$test_strings["success"] = str_repeat($test_strings["success"], $repeated);
$test_strings["failure_early"] = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF" . $test_strings["success"];
$test_strings["failure_late"] = $test_strings["success"] . "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";
foreach ($functions as $function) {
    foreach ($test_strings as $test_string_name => $test_string) {
        $best = PHP_FLOAT_MAX;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; ++$i) {
            $time = hrtime(true);
            $function($test_string);
            $time = hrtime(true) - $time;
            $best = min($time, $best);
        }
        $results[$function][$test_string_name] = $best;
    }
}
$winners = [];
foreach ($test_strings as $test_string_name => $_) {
    $best_function_name = "";
    $best_result = PHP_FLOAT_MAX;
    foreach ($results as $function_name => $function_results) {
        if ($best_result > $function_results[$test_string_name]) {
            $best_function_name = $function_name;
            $best_result = $function_results[$test_string_name];
        }
    }
    $winners[$test_string_name] = $best_function_name;
}
print_r($results);
var_dump($winners);
```

Comment: Which PCRE and which ICONV version were used? The code of `is_utf8_4()` only detects unexpected continuation bytes, but not illegal bytes (i.e. a UTF-8 sequence can never have/start with `0xf5` thru `0xff` (>= 245) or `0xc0` (192) or `0xc1` (193), as per [Unicode 13, § 3.9, D92, Table 3-7](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch03.pdf).

Comment: @AmigoJack `iconv 2.24`, as for pcre, this is what i got for `php -i | grep -i pcre`: ```PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 10.34 2019-11-21
PCRE Unicode Version => 12.1.0
PCRE JIT Support => enabled
PCRE JIT Target => x86 64bit (little endian + unaligned)
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.jit => 1 => 1
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000
(capped, probably boring info after this)
``` - maybe i should add that to the answer?

Comment: Execute `echo PCRE_VERSION;` as per [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.constants.php), too, so we don't miss any detail.

Comment: @AmigoJack PCRE_VERSION is set to `10.34 2019-11-21`

Answer (score 2):

> has anyone actually benchmarked to check which method is faster?

I investigated this topic when implementing pure msgpack serialization, and the fastest way to distinguish between utf8 and non-utf8 strings I found was to use a [specially crafted regex](https://github.com/rybakit/msgpack.php/blob/66ca2c3948d72068ca0c8b9a4f599f822a7fe2c3/src/Packer.php#L20-L29)

```
/\A(?:
      [\x00-\x7F]++                      # ASCII
    | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
    |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
    | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
    |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
    |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
    | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
    |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
)*+\z/x
```

which can be up to 2x faster than `//u`. Here are some benchmark results I made on PHP 7.3: https://gist.github.com/rybakit/2c75152577fdcb9f4718d44e7123a539#file-output-txt.

*Note, however, that `pcre.jit` must be enabled to achieve this, which is usually not a problem as it is enabled (set to 1) [by default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php).*

Comment: interesting! btw seems this question should be re-visited when PHP8.1 is released, a `Alex Dowad` is optimizing mb_check_encoding() in php8.1-dev: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/be1a2155 (the new version still doesn't seem to be on par with preg_ though: https://news-web.php.net/php.internals/115676 - but too early to tell for sure, 8.1 isn't released yet after all)